# Why are contacts synced between our two phones?

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-synchronization

I had a iPhone 4 and after 2 years got an iPhone 5. I gave my wife the 4 and we share contacts if I add one it goes to her phone if I delete hers on my phone it delete from her phone too.

How can we prevent this from happening?

Comment: You don't have a question here—are you trying to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Both Phones have the same iCloud account set up.
Every person should have a unique iCloud account.